# AppEngine Objectify: How does it handle Object Merges?

Tags: google-app-engine, merge, objectify

I read that objectify can handle multiple requests from different clients. During a transaction it throws an Exception if the second client tries to update the same object.

They recommend to send the request again, if such an exception was thrown.

```
class ClassX {
    public String a;
    public String b;
}
```

But what if:
User 1 updates ObjectX.a in the same time User 2 tries to update ObjectX.b?

Does objectify merges these changes? or is the last update "the one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I am using now:

I am storing a unique ID within the Object which is stored online. This ID is not the Objectidentifier.

If a user tries to change the online object, I first make sure that the ID he sends with its changes, is the same than the one which is stored online. 
If they are the same, I push the update to the online object and create a new ID (UUID i.e.). This makes sure, that when another user tries to update the object he must have the new object UUID, to be able to update the online object.

Answer (score 2):

It will be helpful to understand optimistic concurrency and versioning; start with this:

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts#Transactions

Let's say you have two transactions that run concurrently, "set value a" and "set value b". The first time they both run, the first commit will succeed and the second will fail. Objectify will retry the second transaction, which will succeed. Optimistic concurrency gives you the equivalent of a serialized set of transactions.

This means you must be careful about how you structure transactions - they must be idempotent. "Add 5 to b" is not an idempotent transaction; if it runs multiple times (and it could; the datastore may produce ConcurrentModificationException even on success) you will get the wrong value. "Set b to 5" is an idempotent transaction.

Comment: Yes, thats what I read. But it does not explain it enough. 
If User 1 changes the same thing as User 2, the changes of the last transaction "wins". But what, if they change different things on the same object?

Comment: Imagine the transactions are run in serial, one after the other. That is what you will get if multiple transactions try to modify the same entity groups.

Comment: Yes, I get that. So, imagine 2 Users have a copy of object x in their local cache. Object x has 2 different Stringmembers a and b. Lets say string a is "i am a" and string b "i am b". Now user 1 wants to change string a to "update user 1" and user 2 wants to update string b to "update user 2".

What ends up in the online object if user 2 does not have the updated object from user 1?

Does it simply override the changes from user 1, so that the online object contains object.a="i am a" object.b="update user 2"?

If yes, how do I avoid that?

Comment: You are overthinking this; caching has no logical effect on transactions. If txn1 sets a, and txn2 sets b, then after both transactions commit both a and b will be set.